# Can Ag UserControl expose properties exposed for XAML to bind to?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-2.0

I have a new UserControl backed by `UserControl01.cs` that is exposing two properties. One is a plain old CLR property, the other the newer DP property format.
eg:

```
string PropertyOne {get;set;}
```

and the second property is a public DP (construct is too long to list here).

From the XAML side, I wish to expose these value. How can I do that?

On both properties (old CLR as well as second DP wrapper format) I've tried syntax like:

```
 <TextBlock Text={Binding Prop1}/>
 <TextBlock Text={Binding Source=., Path=Prop1}/>
```

I've tried putting a ref to the class type in the Resource dictionary and referencing it with

```
 <TextBlock Text={Binding Source={StaticReference myType}, Path=Prop1}/>
```

but that obviously ends up being a stack overflow as the dictionary instantiates a second copy of the Control.

I read a post somewhere that in WPF one can `x:Name` the control itself, and then

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding {ElementName=theName, Path=Prop1}"/>
```

but we don't have ElementName binding in Ag, so that's not the way.

1. How can I bind to the UserControl's property? Any property!
2. If that's not possible, and you can only bind to DTO's or other BO's, what's the guiding logic/explanation as to how we should design UserControls that want to expose their values?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 3 has control to control binding.
http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=187309